# Laravel resource controller with AJAX form validation

Tags: ajax, laravel, model-view-controller

I want to validate the form with AJAX, because when the normal validation fails, the uploaded files are gone.

I get a JSON response but at the working URL: /properties, instead of the form properties/create.

This is an example of the response:

```
{"error":{"title":["The title must be at least 10 max:50 characters."],"asking_price":["The asking price must be at least 10000."],"description":["The description must be at least 100 characters."],"feat_image_path":["The feat image path has invalid image dimensions."]}}
```

I tried a lot of things, but none is working.

Am I doing something wrong logically, or is it the URL of the AJAX script??

Thanks in advance, Sander

This is the blade file with the AJAX script.

```
@section('tinymce')
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/izqu9favecmjvbbfp1dhe96fphutb1stn4aqs7363k6j8trm/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#description'
    });

</script>
@stop
<x-slot name="header">
    <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
        {{ __('Properties') }}
    </h2>
</x-slot>


<div class="py-12">
    <div class=" mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
            <div class="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
                <h1 class="text-2xl px-12 font-bold w-full my-4">Add Property<span class="text-sm ml-2 text-red-500 italic">* is required</span></h1>


                <div class="container my-4 xl:text-lg text-center">

                    <div class="w-full mx-auto">

                        @if ($errors->any())
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        @endif

                        <div class="alert alert-danger print-error-msg" style="display:none">
                            <ul></ul>
                        </div>

                        {{-- Add Porperty Form --}}

                        <form action="../properties" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="create_property_form" class="bg-white shadow-md rounded mb-4 xl:mb-8 w-full">
                            @csrf
                            <h2 class="text-center text-xl font-bold w-full my-4">General Information</h2>

                            {{-- Title --}}
                            <div class="form-wrapper w-full flex flex-wrap px-8">
                                <div class="mb-4 xl:mb-8 w-full xl:w-1/2 px-4">
                                    <label class="block text-gray-500 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="title">
                                        Property Title*
                                    </label>
                                    <input class="block shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-500 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="title" type="text" placeholder="Title of the property" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}" required>
                                    <span class="error title-error"></span>
                                </div>
                                {{-- Asking Price --}}
                                <div class="mb-4 xl:mb-8 w-full xl:w-1/2 px-4">
                                    <label class="block text-gray-500 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="asking_price">
                                        Asking Price*
                                    </label>
                                    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-500 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="asking_price" name="asking_price" type="number" placeholder="Price in $ USD" value="{{ old('asking_price') }}" required>
                                    <span class="error asking_price-error"></span>
                                </div>

                                <h2 class="text-center text-xl font-bold w-full my-4">Adress</h2>
                                {{-- Street --}}
                                <div class="mb-4 xl:mb-8 w-full xl:w-2/3 px-4">
                                    <label class="block text-gray-500 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="street">
                                        Street*
                                    </label>
                                    <input class="block shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-500 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="street" name="street" type="text" placeholder="Name of the street" value="{{ old('street') }}" required>
                                    <span class="error street-error"></span>
                                </div>
                                {{-- Number --}}
                                <div class="mb-4 xl:mb-8 w-full xl:w-1/3 px-4">
                                    <label class="block text-gray-500 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="number">
                                        Number*
                                    </label>
                                    <input class="block shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-500 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="number" name="number" type="text" placeholder="Appt/house number" value="{{ old('number') }}" required>
                                    <span class="error number-error"></span>
                                </div>
                                {{-- Zip Code --}}
                                <div class="mb-4 xl:mb-8  w-full xl:w-1/3 px-4">
                                    <label class="block text-gray-500 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="zip_code">
                                        Zip Code
                                    </label>
                                    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-500 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="zip_code" name="zip_code" type="text" placeholder="Zip / Postal code" value="{{ old('zip_code') }}">
                                    <span class="error zip_code-error"></span>
                                </div>
                                {{-- City --}}
                                <div class="mb-4 xl:mb-8 w-full xl:w-1/3 px-4">
                                    <label class="block text-gray-500 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="city">
                                        City*
                                    </label>
                                    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-500 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="city" name="city" type="text" placeholder="eg. 'New Tork'" value="{{ old('city') }}" required>
                                    <span class="error city-error"></span>
                                </div>
                                {{-- Location --}}
                                <div class="mb-4 xl:mb-8 w-full xl:w-1/3 px-4">
                                    <label class="block text-gray-500 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="location">
                                        Location*
                                    </label>
                                    <select name="location_id" id="location_id" class="w-full">
                                        @foreach ($locations as $location)
                                        <option value="{{ $location->id }}">{{ $location-> name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                {{-- Coördinates --}}

                                <h2 class="text-center text-xl font-bold w-full my-4">Position<span class="text-sm ml-2 text-gray-500">Get coördinates with <a href="https://www.google.com/maps" target="_blank" class="text-blue-500">Google Maps</a> or <a href="https://www.latlong.net/" target="_blank" class="text-blue-500">Latlong</a> </span></h2>

                                {{-- Latitude --}}
                                <div class="mb-4 xl:mb-8 w-full xl:w-1/2 px-4">
                                    <label class="block text-gray-500 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="latitude">
                                        Latitude*
                                    </label>
                                    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-500 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="latitude" name="latitude" min="11.979144" max="18.145982" step="0.000001" type="number" placeholder="eg. 12.123456" value="{{ old('latitude') }}" required>
                                    <span class="error latitude-error"></span>
                                </div>
                                {{-- Longitude --}}
                                <div class="mb-4 xl:mb-8 w-full xl:w-1/2 px-4">
                                    <label class="block text-gray-500 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="longitude">
                                        Longitude*
                                    </label>
                                    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-500 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="longitude" name="longitude" min="-68.440281" max="-62.966999" step="0.000001" type="number" placeholder="eg. -64.123456" value="{{ old('longitude') }}" required>
                                    <span class="error longitude-error"></span>
                                </div>

                                {{-- Details --}}

                                <h2 class="text-center text-xl font-bold w-full my-4">Property Details</h2>

                                {{-- Built Year --}}
                                <div class="mb-4 xl:mb-8 w-full xl:w-4/12 px-4">
                                    <label class="block text-gray-500 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="built_in">
                                        Built in Year*
                                    </label>
                                    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-500 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="built_in" name="built_in" min="1900" step="1" type="number" placeholder="YYYY" value="{{ old('built_in') }}" required>
                                    <span class="error built_in-error"></span>
                                </div>
                                {{-- Indoor Area --}}
                                <div class="mb-4 xl:mb-8 w-full xl:w-4/12 px-4">
                                    <label class="block text-gray-500 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="area_size_indoor">
                                        Indoor Area Size*
                                    </label>
                                    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-500 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="area_size_indoor" name="area_size_indoor" type="number" placeholder="Size in sqm (m2)" step="1" value="{{ old('area_size_indoor') }}" required>
                                    <small>1 sqft = 0.09290304 sqm</small>
                                    <span class="error area_size_indoor-error"></span>
                                </div>
                                {{-- Outdoor Area --}}
                                <div class="mb-4 xl:mb-8 w-full xl:w-4/12 px-4">
                                    <label class="block text-gray-500 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="area_size_outdoor">
                                        Outdoor Area Size*
                                    </label>
                                    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-500 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="area_size_outdoor" name="area_size_outdoor" type="number" placeholder="Size in sqm (m2)" step="1" value="{{ old('area_size_outdoor') }}" required>
                                    <small>1 sqft = 0.09290304 sqm</small>
                                    <span class="error area_size_outdoor-error"></span>
                                </div>
                                {{-- Bedrooms --}}
                                <div class="mb-4 xl:mb-8 w-full xl:w-4/12 px-4">
                                    <label class="block text-gray-500 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="bedrooms">
                                        Bedrooms*
                                    </label>
                                    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-500 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="bedrooms" name="bedrooms" type="number" step="1" value="{{ old('bedrooms') }}" required>
                                    <span class="error bedrooms-error"></span>
                                </div>
                                {{-- Bathrooms --}}
                                <div class="mb-4 xl:mb-8 w-full xl:w-4/12 px-4">
                                    <label class="block text-gray-500 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="bathrooms">
                                        Bathrooms*
                                    </label>
                                    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-500 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="bathrooms" name="bathrooms" type="number" step="1" value="{{ old('bathrooms') }}" required>
                                    <span class="error bathrooms-error"></span>
                                </div>
                                {{-- Property Type --}}
                                <div class="mb-4 xl:mb-8 w-full xl:w-4/12 px-4">
                                    <label class="block text-gray-500 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="property_type">
                                        Property Type*
                                    </label>
                                    <select name="property_type" id="property_type" class="w-full">
                                        <option value="Villa">Villa</option>
                                        <option value="Chalet">Chalet</option>
                                        <option value="Appartment">Appartment</option>
                                        <option value="Condo">Condo</option>
                                        <option value="Lot">Lot</option>
                                        <option value="Penthouse">Penthouse</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                {{-- Desciption --}}
                                <div class="mb-4 xl:mb-8 w-full">
                                    <label class="block text-gray-500 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="description">
                                        Description*
                                    </label>
                                    <textarea class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-500 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="description" name="description">
                                    {{ old('description') }}
                                    </textarea>
                                    <span class="error description-error"></span>
                                </div>
                                {{-- Featured Image --}}
                                <div class="mb-4 xl:mb-8 w-full xl:w-1/2 px-4">
                                    <label class="block text-gray-500 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="feat_image_path">
                                        Featured Image*
                                    </label>
                                    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-500 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="feat_image_path" name="feat_image_path" type="file" value="{{ old('feat_image_path') }}" required>
                                    <span class="error feat_image_path-error"></span>
                                </div>
                                {{-- Gallery Images --}}
                                <div class="mb-4 xl:mb-8 w-full xl:w-1/2 px-4">
                                    <label class="block text-gray-500 text-base font-bold mb-2" for="bathrooms">
                                        Gallery Images
                                    </label>
                                    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-500 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" type="file" name="file[]" id="file" required="" multiple>
                                    <span class="error file-error"></span>
                                </div>
                                {{-- Submit --}}
                                <div class=" mb-4 xl:mb-8 mx-auto w-48">
                                    <input class="py-2 bg-green-300 hover:bg-green-200 text-white w-full font-bold rounded shadow" data-resource="" value="Submit Property" type="submit">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The AJAX script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#create_property_form").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            let _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
            let title = $("input[name='asking_price']").val();
            let latitude = $("input[name='latitude']").val();
            let longitude = $("input[name='longitude']").val();
            let description = $("textarea[name='description']").val();
            let feat_image_path = $("textarea[name='feat_image_path']").val();


            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ url('/properties/create') }}"
                , type: 'POST'
                , data: {
                    _token: _token
                    , title: title
                    , latitude: latitude
                    , longitude: longitude
                    , description: description
                    , feat_image_path: feat_image_path
                }
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data.error)
                    if ($.isEmptyObject(data.error)) {
                        alert(data.success);
                    } else {
                        printErrorMsg(data.error);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        function printErrorMsg(msg) {
            $.each(msg, function(key, value) {
                console.log(key);
                $('.' + key + '_err').text(value);
            });
        }
    });
```

I have one route for the resource controller:

```
 Route::resource('properties', 'App\Http\Controllers\User\PropertyController');
```

My goal is to only show errors, when no error I add everything in the DB.

Here is the store method:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{

    // Validate input
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'title' => 'required|unique:properties|min:10 max:50',
        'asking_price' => 'required|numeric|min:10000|max:1000000000',
        'street' => 'required|min:3',
        'number' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required|min:3',
        'latitude' => 'required|between:9,12',
        'longitude' => 'required|between:9,12',
        'built_in' => 'required|numeric',
        'area_size_indoor' => 'required|numeric',
        'area_size_outdoor' => 'required|numeric',
        'bedrooms' => 'required|numeric',
        'bathrooms' => 'required|numeric',
        'description' => 'required|min:100',
        'feat_image_path' => 'required|image|dimensions:min_width=1500,min_height=800|max:2500', 
    ]);

    if ($validator->passes()) {

        return response()->json(['success'=>'Added new records.']);
        
    }

    return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()]);

    // Generate random number for filename
    $random = rand(1111,9999) * rand(1, 9);

    // Validate Featured Image
    if($request->hasFile('feat_image_path'))
    {
        // Make a full size imaye
        ImageIvn::make($request->feat_image_path)->resize(1500,800)->save(public_path('img/' . $random . '_feat.jpg'))
        ->resize(400,300)->save(public_path('img/' . $random . '_feat_thumb.jpg'));
    }

    // Store Property
    $property = new Property([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'slug' => Str::slug($request->title),
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'street' => $request->street,
        'number' => $request->number,
        'zip_code' => $request->zip_code,
        'city' => $request->city,
        'asking_price' => $request->asking_price,
        'status' => 'For Sale',
        'location_id' => $request->location_id,
        'property_type' => $request->property_type,
        'latitude' => $request->latitude,
        'longitude' => $request->longitude,
        'built_in' => $request->built_in,
        'area_size_indoor' => $request->area_size_indoor,
        'area_size_outdoor' => $request->area_size_outdoor,
        'bedrooms' => $request->bedrooms,
        'bathrooms' => $request->bathrooms,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'feat_image_path' => 'img/' . $random . '_feat.jpg',
    ]);
    $property->save();

    /**
     * Uploaded gallery images are stored with the use of the property ID as FK
     */

    // Validate Gallery Images
    if($request->hasFile('file'))
    {
        $request->validate([
            'file.*' => 'image'
        ]);

        $files = $request->file('file');

        // Generate images
        foreach($files as $file) {
            
            // Generate random number for filename
            $rand = $property->id . '-' . rand(99,999) * rand(99,999);
            
            // Create Full size image
            ImageIvn::make($file)->resize(1200,900)->save(public_path('img/' . $rand . '_full.jpg'));

            // Save in DB
            $image = new Image([
                'property_id' => $property->id,
                'image_path' => 'img/' . $rand . '_full.jpg',
                'size' => 'full',
            ]);
            $image->save();

            // Create thumbnail size image
            ImageIvn::make($file)->resize(1200,900)->save(public_path('img/' . $rand . '_thumb.jpg'));

            // Store in DB
            $image = new Image([
                'property_id' => $property->id,
                'image_path' => 'img/' . $rand . '_thumb.jpg',
                'size' => 'thumb',
            ]);
            $image->save();
        }
    }
    
    return $this->index()->with(["message" => "Property "  . $property->name . " is added"]);
    
}
```

Comment: The errors are displaying on a white page in JSON format at the url: /properties instead of on the same epage, which is /properties/create.

Comment: So instead of displaying the error in the blade view, it is displayed separate as only JSON.

Comment: yes i do. I could not solve it. Still getting the JSON error in JSON format on a blank page at the wrong URL.

Comment: yes i tried that too